# Use effect for every time that location.pathname changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have this variable called `nameScreen` that i need to change our value every time that the location.path change:

```
<Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
    {nameScreen}
</Typography>
```

I try:

```
const [nameScreen, setNameScreen] = useState('')

const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
    changeTitleHeader()
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
},[location.pathname])

  const changeTitleHeader = () => {
      if (location.pathname === '/home') {
        setNameScreen('Welcome to home!')
      }
      else if(location.pathname === '/users') {
          setNameScreen('Users')
      }
      else if(location.pathname === '/companies') {
        setNameScreen('Companies')
      }
  }
```

I need to everytime that my `location.pathname` changes, this typograph component have a new value based in the name of the route.

My `useEffect()` is not being called when the `location.pathname` is changed. How i can fix this?

Comment: I presume you are using the router for routing your paths. Why don't you add a prop to every route with the title and pass it in the router rather than having a state in the container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a dependency on the `location.pathname` in your `changeTitleHeader` function as well, not just the `useEffect`. The function remembers the initial value of `location.pathname` and never updates it, so it does nothing new on call.

You can use `useCallback` for this purpose. Here's the code:

```
const changeTitleHeader = useCallback(() => { sameThing() }, [location.pathname]);
```

I'm assuming here, that the state isn't updated as expected, but if your useEffect isn't actually firing, then the issue might be elsewhere. Hope this helps.